# MS Flow (Azure) and Double quote

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I hope you can help me as I'm a little stuck on this problem and cannot find a nice solution.

I would like to create an HTTP POST and the body of my request need to be something like this

```
 .... (code)
 {
        "table":"DimDate"
 }
 .... (code)
```

The "table" : "Dimdate" is built , part by a string variable ( myVar='{"table":"' ) and a dynamic field (all stored on another string variable called myString).

Meaning I've got on my MS Flow a variable myString = "table": "DimDate"

Till there no issue. My problem appear when I want to embed my variable in the body of the HTTP Post.

It seems all is converted as

```
   .... (code)
 {
        \"table\":\"DimDate\"
 }
 .... (code)
```

Question is why do I have those "\" ? and how to remove them ?

I've check and it seems they appear by default from the start , in my different variables. How to remove them when I use the variable myString in the HTTP POST body ?

I've already try to convert to plain-text, look for use char (no idea how), etc...

Any idea ?

[image: Variable setting]

[image: HTTP POST body]

Thanks

Addendum

a) Idea is to be able to add in the body of my HTTP POST the following body

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 2,
  "Objects": [
    {  "Table": "table1" },
    {  "Table": "table2"},
    {  "Table": "table3"}
  ],
  "RetryCount": 2,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```

b) For that I set an initial variable _mystring as '{"table":"'
c) with a loop I put in a variable _myVar a concatenation of _mystring with a array of table ( table1,2 and 3) . the variable _myVar at the end is ok. No issue there
d) the HTTP POST body appear on the screen "as this" :

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 4,
  "Objects": [
    {
      "Table": "@{variables('_Table')}"
    }
  ],
  "RetryCount": 2,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```

e) Like that all appear perfect. The problem is that when I run the flow, the body of the HTTP is not OK as even the variable _mystring which is used. It seems the " is replaced by \" and this generate a wrong output of the HTTP POST.

Is there a way to avoid Microsoft Flow replace the " by \" ?

Miguel

Comment: can you post the image of HTTP response ?

Comment: Added. each time I put a double quote, it add me a "/"

Comment: Can you show how you're construction that string?

Comment: Added at the bottom of the "question" :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally an easy solution was found.
Microsoft fix that during their next Logic App release.
Topic close